# Cohesive vs. coherent

Tags: english, discourse-analysis

Is the following sentence cohesive or coherent? Or both?

> Ali loves fish. He lives in the north.

It might be of interest that cities are next to the sea in the north.

Comment: is this question linguistic?

Comment: I think that we should cover semantics under the heading of linguistics, yes.

Comment: But are "cohesive" and "coherent" standard terms in semantics? I've seen both of them used in many different ways.

Comment: @LouisRhys It's Discourse Analysis, which is a field of Linguistics (too).

Comment: @jlawler They are in Discourse Analysis, as far as I know, which is  what the question is about. By the way, this just reminded me to add the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text is **cohesive** but I don't think it's also **coherent**.

**Cohesion** is achieved through some devices, such as the pronouns (you used *he* in your example)<sup>**1**</sup>, so there is cohesion. Both sentences are about Ali.

But the text has no **coherence**, there is no (necessary) logic correlation between loving fish and living in the North.

---

<sup>**1**: As also Mark reminded me in the comments below this answer, the text is cohesive if Ali is a man. Since Ali is also a female's name, the text might lose its cohesion if the text talks about an "Ali = woman".</sup>

Comment: I don't think that coherence requires _necessary_ correlation, merely correlation within a certain framework of knowledge.

Comment: @MarkBeadles That last sentence, that the OP added, is not part of the text, therefore how can we take it into account when analyzing the text? Considering only the quoted part (the text), there is no coherence; there is no logic correlation between the first and second sentence. By this I mean: *what north? For who? All people in this "north" love fish?* Like I told the OP in another place, take 2 people from Sweden and 2 from India: **is it obvious/logic** that the first two love fish rather than the second two? No, it's not obvious. Where is the "link" between those two sentences?

Comment: I think we are talking at cross terms. I understand coherence as pertaining to semantic and contextual continuity, and cohesion as pertaining to syntactical and textual continuity. Since coherence involves meaning it depends on contextual knowledge, not just textual knowledge. E.g., "Cohesion alone is not sufficient for the interpretation of the discourse. Comprehenders generate inferences on the basis of _background knowledge_ and discourse constraints." (Strazny's encyclopedia of linguistics). It may be that you are using the term differently.

Comment: I'm not using them differently. Actually what you said explains my answer: This text has continuity (it is cohesive "Ali > he"), but, using your words, there is no contextual continuity. There is no logical link between Ali that loves fish and him living in the north. Those are both things related to Ali (cohesion), but they have nothing to do with each other (coherence). You could say there might be some other info, but this is the text we must analyse. The OP asked about that text, not that plus something else that we can imagine.

Comment: Agreed. Of course, "Ali > he" is only true if Ali is a man. In America Ali is a common female name, in which case we might believe the sentence is not even cohesive. ;)

Comment: @MarkBeadles Ahah yes! When talking about this topic to someone else, I was told that same thing! It is indeed ambiguous. I'll point the OP to the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Without understanding the universe of discourse we can't make determination if sentences are coherent.

In your question, you give some context about this universe. This context could be seen as giving coherence to the sentences. In particular, if we regard "the North" as exophoric in relation to the cities near the sea, then the text is coherent.

In a different universe, or in a universe constisting only of the two sentences and no other text or knowledge, then we cannot say they are coherent, rather merely cohesive.

Comment: I'd need to post the same comment I posted under my answer but well, I don't want to repeat it. :)

Comment: For example, giving contextual knowledge surrounding the discourse, we might say the second sentence stands in an explanatory relation to the first. Yes, we can only say this using extra-textual knowledge. Absent such knowledge we cannot say if the sentences are coherent. But we are presented with such knowledge.

Comment: Given additional info, they might make more sense, maybe. But we must analyze the text as is, otherwise it's not discourse analysis, it's guessing/hypothesizing. There is not logical correlation between the two statements. As you said in the comment above too, cohesion alone is not sufficient, and indeed, this text is not clear. Its meaning is not 100% clear and logic, that's why I said it lacked coherence. If it didn't, you'd understand it clearly, but now we're guessing.

Comment: I suspect that this may be homework relating to essay evaluation. If that suspicion is correct, then you probably are right since the writer would be expected to link the sentences with a smooth transition or endophora. More generally, though, I think that context and shared knowledge is fair game.